# Confusion in use of uart_ops and tty_operation in serial driver

Tags: serial-port, linux-device-driver, device-driver, tty

I'm learning Linux serial device driver . For that I've gone through sample driver code and read LDD3.
I've confusion at file_operations performed on tty serial port.

Basically two files tty_io.c(tty layer)[tty_io.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/tty_io.c?v=3.4) and serial_core.c(core layer) [serial_core.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/drivers/tty/serial/serial_core.c?v=3.4) files are using **file_operations** structures.
So i've confusion that when any **read** or **write** or **open** operations occur from application side,then which file_operation structure comes into action.

Please provide possible solution.
Thank you.

Comment: From user space you usually do `open()`, `read()` or `write()` system calls either directly or via libc.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko...May be you are getting wrong..My question is that ,from both files `tty_io.c` and `serial_core.c` which **file_operation** structure will come into picture when `open()`  , `read()` , `write()` system calls occurs ?

Comment: Depends on what device node you are using and which driver is associated with that node.

Comment: I'm using PCI card which opens two RS-232 port.So 8250 driver is associated with that.

Comment: Obviously `serial_core.c` provides you the functionality.